# Pass lambda that captures "this" to obj in member initializer list

Tags: c++, lambda, closures, member-initialization

I have the following problem: I define a class `task` that lives within another class object. I want to save a closure inside that `task` class to invoke it later. Now how excactly am I supposed to initialize the `task` object within the container class? I can't use `this` at "top level" (e.g. when I use it in direct member initialization. On the other hand, when I decltype() an empty lambda it gives me the wrong type it seems as it doesn't close over `this`. Check out the following code:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:3,endLineNumber:32,positionColumn:3,positionLineNumber:32,selectionStartColumn:3,selectionStartLineNumber:32,startColumn:3,startLineNumber:32),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+Callable%3E%0Astruct+task%0A%7B%0A++++task(Callable+fn)%0A++++:+++fn_%7Bfn%7D%0A++++%7B+%7D%0A%0A++++auto+do_stuff()+%7B%0A++++++++fn_()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++Callable+fn_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+container%0A%7B%0A++++container()%0A++++++++:++task_(%5Bthis%5D()+-%3E+void+%7B+this-%3Eprint()%3B+%7D)%0A++++%7B+%7D%0A%0A++++auto+print()+-%3E+void+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22Hello+World!!%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++auto+execute()+%7B%0A++++++++task_.do_stuff()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++task%3Cdecltype(%5B%5D()%7B%7D)%3E+task_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++container+a%3B%0A%0A++++a.execute()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.31070496083551,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:52.689295039164485,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename Callable>
struct task
{
    task(Callable fn)
    :   fn_{fn}
    { }

    auto do_stuff() {
        fn_();
    }

    Callable fn_;
};

struct container
{
    container()
        :  task_([this]() -> void { this->print(); })
    { }

    auto print() -> void {
        printf("Hello World!\n");
    }

    auto execute() {
        task_.do_stuff();
    }

    task<decltype([](){})> task_;
};

int main()
{
    container a;

    a.execute();
}
```

This yields specifically:

```
<source>:20:12: error: no matching function for call to 'task<container::<lambda()> >::task(container::container()::<lambda()>)'
   20 |         :  task_([this]() -> void { this->print(); })
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I create a closure over `this` in direct member initialization or in the member initializer list?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to assign different functionalities to this `task_`, you need type erasure: `std::function<void()> task_;`. Also, you need to have `print()` before ctor in your code.

If you only need one functionality, then `task_` is a member function basically.

If neither of these suits you, you can still introduce a layer of indirection in the hierarchy, `containerBase`:

```
struct containerBase
{
    void print() {
        printf("Hello World!\n");
    }

    auto g() { return [this]() -> void { this->print(); }; }
};

struct container : containerBase
{
    container()
        :  task_(g())
    { }

public:
    auto execute() {
        task_.do_stuff();
    }

    task<decltype(std::declval<containerBase>().g())> task_;
};
```

Comment: Interesting solution, however the this pointer in the second example will be of type containerBase. So I would need virtual calls to reach containers member functions which is not ideal. Is there no more direct solution?

Comment: @glades The idea is, you put nearly everything to `containerBase`; only the ctor (that assigns `task_`), the functions calling `task_` and `task_` itself are in `container`.

Comment: I get that but that essentially means that every container that includes the task object would have its hierarchy extended to suit its needs. This is not ideal. I'm thinking that maybe std::bind is not a bad solution for this after all.